# I have a data and I want to specify the color to be orange in primary and yellow in secondary using regular expression in python

Tags: python, networkx

```
{"id": 764046068, "label": "edge 6 secondary", "nodes_in_edge": [5653832464, 7138043089, 7138030356], "width": "2'", "speed": "20 mph"}
{"id": 1053591753, "label": "edge 8 primary", "nodes_in_edge": [5475082077, 9682439803], "width": "4'", "speed": "50 mph"}
```

I am using Networkx and Object oriented programming for graph visualization. How can I specify the color to be orange in primary and yellow in secondary for graph visualization using regular expression in Python?

Comment: How would you do it without regular expressions?

Comment: Or, more to the point, why do you think you need regular expressions for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, assuming you have a list (`L`) of dicts, there is no need to use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) here :

```
for edge in L:
    nodes = edge["nodes_in_edge"]
    edges = [(nodes[i], nodes[i+1], edge) for i in range(len(nodes)-1)]
    G.add_edges_from(edges)

colors, widths = zip(*[(("orange" if "primary" in d["label"] else "yellow"),
                       int(d["width"].strip("'"))) for _, _, d in G.edges(data=True)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, edge_color=colors, width=widths, ax=ax, font_size=12)

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]